# 7zip go down 1 directory in all folders then zip up all folders seperately

Tags: python, windows, 7zip

With the python script below I'm trying to make it so it goes down 1 directory to all folders within the set "path_to_dir", then zip up all the folders inside them individually.

For example if I set the path_to_dir = "C:/folder1/" it will go inside "C:/folder1/subdir1/", "C:/folder1/subdir2/", "C:/folder1/subdir3/" and so forth, and within these subdirectories are folders that I want 7zip to zip up seperately.
But the result with the script is that it zips up all folders within the subdirectories into a single zip file.

How can I modify the script so it does this?

```
import os
import subprocess

path_to_dir = "C:/folder1/"

for subdirectory in os.listdir(path_to_dir):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path_to_dir, subdirectory)):
        zip_filename = subdirectory + ".zip"
        output_path = os.path.join(path_to_dir, subdirectory, zip_filename)
        command = f'7z a -tzip -mx0 "{output_path}" "{os.path.join(path_to_dir, subdirectory)}/*" -x!*.txt'
        subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a directory, which has subdirectories in it, then in each of these, there is more subdirectories? And you want to zip each of those folders?

Comment: You could add an extra loop that get the subdirectories in a subdirectory, then use your same code for zipping to zip those instead

Comment: Like so: ```for subdirectory in os.listdir(path_to_dir):``` 
```if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path_to_dir, subdirectory)):``` 
```for sub in os.listdir(os.path.join(path_to_dir, subdirectory)```
```if os.path,isdir(os.path.join(path_to_dir, subdirectory, sub)``` 
Then your code to zip the files

Comment: Thanks that did it ended up looping one more time

Comment: `for subdir in os.listdir(parent_dir):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(parent_dir, subdir)
    if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):
        for subsubdir in os.listdir(subdir_path):
            subsubdir_path = os.path.join(subdir_path, subsubdir)
                zip_filename = subsubdir_path + ".zip"
                subprocess.run(["7z", "a", "-r", "-mx0", "-tzip", zip_filename, subsubdir_path])
                if os.path.exists(zip_filename):                   
                    shutil.rmtree(subsubdir_path)
input("Press Enter to exit...")`